# Getting values from array

Tags: php, arrays

I know this is a newbie question,

I extracted some preformatted json out of javascript, that looks like this:

```
[[[455837.99,2896882.36],[455862.44,2896888.35],[455868.79,2896860.14],[455864.3,2896852.78],[455845.76,2896848],[455837.99,2896882.36]]]
```

I tried an online formatted that shows me the array looks something like this:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 455837.99
                [1] => 2896882.36
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 455862.44
                [1] => 2896888.35
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 455868.79
                [1] => 2896860.14
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 455864.3
                [1] => 2896852.78
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => 455845.76
                [1] => 2896848
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [0] => 455837.99
                [1] => 2896882.36
            )

    )

)
```

All the third [0]'s are what I need as an X, so everything that starts with 455. and All the [1]'s are the Y's. I would like these two to be grouped together, the respective X and Y.

My problem is I am not sure how to access them out of the area, I have tried this:

```
preg_match_all('/\[{3}.*\]{3}/', $data, $matches);
$arr=array();
foreach ($matches[0] as $match)
 {
   $arr[]=json_decode($match);
 }
 echo '<br>';
   $newmatch = json_decode($match);
```

I would really appreciate if someone can point me in the direction of being able to have a loop that basically echo's the X and Y values, whenever I try and echo something from the array I get: 
1) Array to string conversion

I am not sure if that is because of the triple brackets, that its an array in an array in an array.

Comment: You're doing that completely wrong. it's json. you don't use string operations to extract data from it. You use `json_decode()`, from which you'll get a perfectly normal PHP array.

Comment: @MarcB I am not trying to extract data from it, I am trying to tell you that I scraped a JSON string and I am trying to access the array, and I am not sure how to access it - because of its structure.

Comment: So it was scraped in RegExp and then became an Array, that is why I thought I need to decode it twice?

Comment: you decode the main string, then use `$arr[0]`, `$arr[1]`, etc... to get at those subarrays. YOu should NEVER be mangling json strings like you are. it's far too easy to get corrupted json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = "[[[455837.99,2896882.36],[455862.44,2896888.35],[455868.79,2896860.14],[455864.3,2896852.78],[455845.76,2896848],[455837.99,2896882.36]]]";

$data_array = json_decode($data);

if (is_array($data_array) && array_key_exists(0, $data_array)) {
    foreach ($data_array[0] as $element) {
        $x = array_key_exists(0, $element) ? $element[0] : "N/A";
        $y = array_key_exists(1, $element) ? $element[1] : "N/A";

        printf("X: %s | Y: %s\n", $x, $y);
    }
}
```